# How do I return the first non-NULL value in a series of columns for every row? And the second non-NULL value?

Tags: r, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have the following organizational data:

```
EmployeeID <- c(10:15)
Job.Title <- c("Program Manager", "Development Manager", "Developer" , "Developer", "Developer", "Summer Intern")
Level.1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
Level.2 <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2)
Level.3 <- c("",10,10,10,10,10)
Level.4 <- c("","",11,11,11,11)
Level.5 <- c("","","","","",12)
Level.6 <- c("","","","","","")
Pay.Type <- c("Salary", "Salary", "Salary", "Salary", "Salary", "Hourly")
acme = data.frame(EmployeeID, Job.Title, Level.1, Level.2, Level.3, Level.4, Level.5, Level.6, Pay.Type)

acme

  EmployeeID           Job.Title Level.1 Level.2 Level.3 Level.4 Level.5 Level.6 Pay.Type
1         10     Program Manager       1       2                                   Salary
2         11 Development Manager       1       2      10                           Salary
3         12           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary
4         13           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary
5         14           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary
6         15       Summer Intern       1       2      10      11      12           Hourly
```

For each row, I need to identify the first non-NULL value for Level.1 through Level.6, starting from the right with Level.6, then, Level.5, then Level.4 and so on.  I also need to identify the second non-Null value in this same pattern.  The identified values for each row need to be put in new columns, so the final tables looks like this:

```
  EmployeeID           Job.Title Level.1 Level.2 Level.3 Level.4 Level.5 Level.6 Pay.Type Supervisor Manager
1         10     Program Manager       1       2                                   Salary          2       1
2         11 Development Manager       1       2      10                           Salary         10       2
3         12           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary         11      10
4         13           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary         11      10
5         14           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary         11      10
6         15       Summer Intern       1       2      10      11      12           Hourly         12      11
```

Comment: R has NA values. They are a lot better to use then empty character strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `apply` row-wise and get all the indices which are not-null and select the first and the second values to get two columns respectively.

```
acme[, c("Supervisor", "Manager")] <- t(apply(acme[, 8:3], 1, 
                      function(x) c(x[which(x != "")[1]], x[which(x != "")[2]])))

acme

#  EmployeeID           Job.Title Level.1 Level.2 Level.3 Level.4 Level.5 Level.6 Pay.Type Supervisor Manager
#1         10     Program Manager       1       2                                   Salary          2       1
#2         11 Development Manager       1       2      10                           Salary         10       2
#3         12           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary         11      10
#4         13           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary         11      10
#5         14           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary         11      10
#6         15       Summer Intern       1       2      10      11      12           Hourly         12      11
```

---

**EDIT**

If there are many columns, we need to find the index of start and end columns. We can use `grep` for the same

```
mincol <- min(grep("Level", colnames(acme)))
maxcol <- max(grep("Level", colnames(acme)))

 acme[, c("Supervisor", "Manager")] <- t(apply(acme[, maxcol:mincol], 1, 
                      function(x) c(x[which(x != "")[1]], x[which(x != "")[2]])))
```

should work.

In case if we need only `Supervisor` we can ignore the second part.

```
acme[, "Supervisor"] <- t(apply(acme[, maxcol:mincol], 1, 
                            function(x) x[which(x != "")[1]]))
```

Comment: My data frame is much larger and part of a larger code set so referring to columns by order number may cause bugs later if other columns are added or removed.  Should I just create a separate data frame for this task and merge it back, or is there a way to edit the "apply(acme[, 8:3]" to use column names?  I tried: 

acme[, c("Supervisor", "Manager")] <- t(apply(acme[,Level.6, Level.5, Level.4, Level.3, Level.2, Level.1], 1, 
                                              function(x) c(x[which(x != "")[1]], x[which(x != "")[2]])))

And several variations, but that just returns an error.

Comment: Also, how do I return only the Supervisor?

Comment: @Ankie I have updated the answer. Let me know if you still have doubts.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `data.table` "one-liner":

```
library(data.table)
setDT(acme)[melt(acme, measure.vars = patterns("Level.\\d"))[value != ""][
  order(variable), .(Supervisor = value[.N], Manager = value[.N - 1]), by = EmployeeID], 
  on = "EmployeeID"][]

   EmployeeID           Job.Title Level.1 Level.2 Level.3 Level.4 Level.5 Level.6 Pay.Type Supervisor
#1:         10     Program Manager       1       2                                   Salary          2
#2:         11 Development Manager       1       2      10                           Salary         10
#3:         12           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary         11
#4:         13           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary         11
#5:         14           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary         11
#6:         15       Summer Intern       1       2      10      11      12           Hourly         12
   Manager
#1:       1
#2:       2
#3:      10
#4:      10
#5:      10
#6:      11
```

*How it works*

1. The `data.frame` is coerced to `data.table`
2. and it's reshaped from wide to long format in order
3. to remove all rows where the level was given as `""`.
4. Now, the data are ordered by level number (implicitely conveyed as `Level.1`, `Level.2`, etc.)
5. for each employee the last (Supervisor) and second last value (Manager) is extracted creating an intermediate result consisting of three columns.
6. Finally, the intermediate result is joined to `acme` to append the new columns
7. and printed

**Note:** `melt()` will issue a warning message that not all level columns have the same data type. This is caused by mixing integer values with character (`""`) in the definition of the `acme` data.frame. It would have been better to use `NA`instead of `""`. BTW: In that case it would have been possible to streamline the code by using `na.rm = FALSE` with `melt()`

**Note:** The simple alaphybetical ordering in step 4 will work for up to 9 levels (`Level.1` to `Level.9`). In case of more levels, the level number has to be extracted and coerced to integer.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `dplyr` and `tidyr` relying on the reshaping of the data.

```
library(tidyverse)
acme %>%
  gather('level', 'value', starts_with('Level.')) %>%
  group_by(EmployeeID) %>%
  filter(value != '') %>%
  summarise(Supervisor = last(value),
            Manager = nth(value, -2)) %>%
  left_join(acme)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `max.col`.  Find the index of 'Level' columns ('i1'), convert the subset of 'acme' based on 'i1' to `matrix` (`!=""`), apply the `max.col` and get the column index of the `last` TRUE value, subtract 1 to get the second last TRUE value ('i3'), using row/column index extract the elements and create the 'Supervisor' and 'Manager' columns

```
i1 <- grep("Level\\.\\d+", names(acme))
i2 <- max.col(acme[i1]!="", "last")
i3 <- i2-1
acme$Supervisor <- acme[i1][cbind(1:nrow(acme), i2)]
acme$Manager <-  acme[i1][cbind(1:nrow(acme), i3)]
acme
#  EmployeeID           Job.Title Level.1 Level.2 Level.3 Level.4 Level.5 Level.6 Pay.Type Supervisor Manager
#1         10     Program Manager       1       2                                   Salary          2       1
#2         11 Development Manager       1       2      10                           Salary         10       2
#3         12           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary         11      10
#4         13           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary         11      10
#5         14           Developer       1       2      10      11                   Salary         11      10
#6         15       Summer Intern       1       2      10      11      12           Hourly         12      11
```

NOTE: This solution is very straightforward and efficient without any unnecessary reshaping